# Kernel 5.15.0 crash when i remove usb network device from ubuntu 22.04，but kernel 5.15.75 doesn't

Tags: networking, kernel, usb-modem

When I removed the usb network device from ubuntu 22.04, the kernel crashed, so I recompiled the 5.15.75 kernel for ubuntu 22.04, the kernel will not crash at this time.
The 5.15.75 kernel is the source code downloaded from kernel.org, and 5.15.0 is the kernel that comes with the ubuntu distribution
Is it due to a bug in the 5.15.0 kernel, which was fixed in 5.15.75?
The crash log is as follows

```
1,6996,243022202,-;BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000018
1,6997,243022205,-;#PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
1,6998,243022207,-;#PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
6,6999,243022208,-;PGD 800000004df9b067 P4D 800000004df9b067 PUD 0 
4,7000,243022211,-;Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
4,7001,243022213,-;CPU: 3 PID: 154 Comm: kworker/3:2 Tainted: G           OE     5.15.0-43-generic #46-Ubuntu
4,7002,243022216,-;Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 07/29/2019
4,7003,243022217,-;Workqueue: usb_hub_wq hub_event
4,7004,243022222,-;RIP: 0010:__dev_close_many+0x91/0x120
4,7005,243022226,-;Code: fe 48 8b 43 70 48 8d 58 90 49 39 c4 75 cc 4c 89 e7 e8 13 74 07 00 49 8b 04 24 48 8d 58 90 49 39 c4 74 34 48 8b 83 c8 00 00 00 <48> 8b 40 18 48 85 c0 74 08 48 89 df e8 5e 37 56 00 83 a3 c0 00 00
4,7006,243022228,-;RSP: 0018:ffff9c5a4060f930 EFLAGS: 00010206
4,7007,243022229,-;RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff90fc49eb4000 RCX: 0000000000000000
4,7008,243022230,-;RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 00000000fffffe01 RDI: ffffffff8fb1625e
4,7009,243022231,-;RBP: ffff9c5a4060f958 R08: ffffffff90f7f8b0 R09: 0000000000000000
4,7010,243022232,-;R10: ffff90fc4a659000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff9c5a4060f9c0
4,7011,243022233,-;R13: 0000000000000001 R14: ffff9c5a4060f9c0 R15: ffff9c5a4060f9c0
4,7012,243022234,-;FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff90fcbbec0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
4,7013,243022235,-;CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
4,7014,243022236,-;CR2: 0000000000000018 CR3: 000000004dc38004 CR4: 00000000003706e0
4,7015,243022254,-;Call Trace:
4,7016,243022256,-; <TASK>
4,7017,243022258,-; dev_close_many+0x7f/0x120
4,7018,243022261,-; ? vprintk_emit+0x8b/0x230
4,7019,243022265,-; unregister_netdevice_many+0x138/0x590
4,7020,243022267,-; ? vprintk+0x58/0x90
4,7021,243022269,-; unregister_netdevice_queue+0x90/0xe0
4,7022,243022270,-; unregister_netdev+0x1d/0x30
4,7023,243022273,-; usbnet_disconnect+0x5e/0xc0 [usbnet]
4,7024,243022279,-; USBNetDisconnect+0x68/0x80
4,7025,243022285,-; usb_unbind_interface+0x90/0x270
4,7026,243022288,-; __device_release_driver+0x27f/0x290
4,7027,243022291,-; device_release_driver+0x29/0x40
4,7028,243022292,-; bus_remove_device+0xde/0x150
4,7029,243022294,-; device_del+0x19c/0x3f0
4,7030,243022295,-; ? kobject_put+0x53/0x70
4,7031,243022297,-; usb_disable_device+0xde/0x270
4,7032,243022299,-; usb_disconnect.cold+0x7c/0x20c
4,7033,243022302,-; hub_port_connect+0x88/0x8e0
4,7034,243022304,-; ? usb_control_msg+0xfe/0x140
4,7035,243022306,-; hub_port_connect_change+0xa1/0x3b0
4,7036,243022308,-; port_event+0x5b7/0x700
4,7037,243022310,-; hub_event+0x1e7/0x430
4,7038,243022313,-; process_one_work+0x22b/0x3d0
4,7039,243022316,-; worker_thread+0x53/0x410
4,7040,243022318,-; ? process_one_work+0x3d0/0x3d0
4,7041,243022321,-; kthread+0x12a/0x150
4,7042,243022322,-; ? set_kthread_struct+0x50/0x50
4,7043,243022324,-; ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
4,7044,243022328,-; </TASK>
4,7045,243022329,-;Modules linked in: qmi_wwan option(OE) usb_wwan cdc_wdm usbserial usbnet mii intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel vmw_balloon crypto_simd cryptd rapl snd_ens1371 snd_ac97_codec nls_iso8859_1 gameport ac97_bus snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event joydev snd_rawmidi vmwgfx input_leds serio_raw ttm snd_seq drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device cec rc_core snd_timer fb_sys_fops snd syscopyarea sysfillrect soundcore sysimgblt vmw_vmci mac_hid sch_fq_codel ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport ramoops reed_solomon pstore_blk pstore_zone drm efi_pstore mtd ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid crc32_pclmul psmouse ahci e1000 libahci mptspi mptscsih mptbase xhci_pci xhci_pci_renesas scsi_transport_spi pata_acpi i2c_piix4
4,7046,243022369,-;CR2: 0000000000000018
4,7047,243022371,-;---[ end trace 8a6e2984b74b64ab ]---
4,7048,243022373,-;RIP: 0010:__dev_close_many+0x91/0x120
4,7049,243022376,-;Code: fe 48 8b 43 70 48 8d 58 90 49 39 c4 75 cc 4c 89 e7 e8 13 74 07 00 49 8b 04 24 48 8d 58 90 49 39 c4 74 34 48 8b 83 c8 00 00 00 <48> 8b 40 18 48 85 c0 74 08 48 89 df e8 5e 37 56 00 83 a3 c0 00 00
4,7050,243022378,-;RSP: 0018:ffff9c5a4060f930 EFLAGS: 00010206
4,7051,243022379,-;RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff90fc49eb4000 RCX: 0000000000000000
4,7052,243022380,-;RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 00000000fffffe01 RDI: ffffffff8fb1625e
4,7053,243022381,-;RBP: ffff9c5a4060f958 R08: ffffffff90f7f8b0 R09: 0000000000000000
4,7054,243022382,-;R10: ffff90fc4a659000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff9c5a4060f9c0
4,7055,243022383,-;R13: 0000000000000001 R14: ffff9c5a4060f9c0 R15: ffff9c5a4060f9c0
4,7056,243022384,-;FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff90fcbbec0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
4,7057,243022385,-;CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
4,7058,243022386,-;CR2: 0000000000000018 CR3: 000000004dc38004 CR4: 00000000003706e0
```

Comment: If this is a bug in the current Ubuntu kernel, it should be reported, so it can be patched in the next release.

Comment: You are using `5.15.0-43-generic` but Ubuntu is up to at least `5.15.0-52-generic`, so try that one first. Your kernel is also tainted, with propriety, external and unsigned modules, which may or may not be a contributing factor. Eventually, upstream fixes will make their way down to Ubuntu.